# How to stop WPF validation errors dissapearing when moving between tabs?

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, xaml, binding

When switching between tabs my validation errors are disappearing.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer here

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/wpf-validation-errors-disappear-inside-tabcontrol-when-switching-tabitems/

Turns out that you need to wrap your controls in a AdornerDecorator

```
<AdornerDecorator>
     Your controls go here
</AdornerDecorator>
```

It is a bug in WPF

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=295933&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Thank you! I was having this same problem - fixed!

Comment: Thank you very much! this fixed my problem!  :)